# How to call a UIViewController property in custom uiview?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a AVAudioPlayer property in my viewController and I want to draw a circle in my custom uiview if the music is playing.

in my MyViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audio;
```

in my view.h

```
- (void) drawCircle
{

//DRAW Circle
}
```

now i want to check in my View.m if the audio is playing.

i tried to add the following in my View.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) MyViewController *ViewController_audio;
```

and then do `if ([ViewController_audio  _audio].playing) { }` in

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Get rid of the underscore:

```
if ([ViewController_audio audio].playing)
```

or

```
if (ViewController_audio.audio.playing)
```

Either syntax is valid.

P.S. "...it didn't work" is **supremely** unhelpful. Always explain what happens. In your case, I'm assuming that you got a compiler error. So copy and paste the full text of the compiler error, and explicitly tell the line on which it occurs.

Comment: I get following error: Member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union.

Comment: i also tried to call drawCircle in my uiviewcontroller but nothing displays. is there anyway to add the circle as subview?

Answer (score 0):

A view should not have a reference to view controller. This is a bad design.
Instead you should have a flag in view which will be set by your view controller when its playing. The view will read this property & take ui decisions.

From design prospective i would suggest that no decisions should be left to view. It is view controller who has right to think, a view should only display.

Comment: that makes sense,so i should make a bool method in my uiview?

Comment: You can do that. But try to look for a way that your view controller shows or hides something on view and not the view itself does a hide/show